# Problems after converting string to double

Tags: java, double, number-formatting

I am fairly new to java and as such I have no earthly idea why this is not working. Could you please tell me why I am getting this error?

I have already imported the `java.text.NumberFormat`.

```
NumberFormat fmt1 = NumberFormat.getcurrencyInstance();
String r = "12579500";
double s = Double.parseDouble(r);
double t = fmt1.format(s);
```

When compiling I get: incompatible types:

> `string` cannot be converted to `double`

Comment: did you mean `String t = fmt1.format(s);`

Comment: This cannot be your real code: "getcurrency" (all lower case?)
Please add minimal compilable example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: My apologies, it is in fact "getCurrencyInstance"

Comment: Do I need to change "t" to a string value?

Comment: Thank you YCF_L! It worked after changing "t" to a String value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fmt1.format(s)` returns a `String` (the formatted `String` according to the `NumberFormat`).
`double` and `String` are incompariable types.

```
final String formatted = fmt1.format(s);
```

BTW, you've made a typo in `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`.